# Getting ClassCastException for @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-bean

I have application where the parent project is updated with the latest Spring library but in the dependent application I do not want to upgrade the spring beans lib version.
Since the same dependent application we have to make it compatible with the older parents also which uses the older SF libraries. And also dont want to have multiple dependent application for older and newer parents

But now the problem is that I am getting class cast exception when using this dependent application with newer parent application.

```
"org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire cannot be cast to org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire"
```

Please help me if there is any workaround. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Parent application is using SF 4.1.4RELEASE(older) and 5.2.8RELEASE(upgraded)

```
Wed May 05 13:37:28 IST 2021 - java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire cannot be cast to org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:95)
```

Comment: Post the error stacktrack

Comment: If only one of the parent is upgraded then how about copying the dependent project to a new project with updated version. Its always good to version up things from time to time.

Comment: because we have multiple version of parents running at different location, and I want to inject the same dependent application everywhere

Comment: Making a copy of that very same dependent application is no different I guess. U just need to copy it and make a new one with updated version. By doing that you are only affecting the parent app and rest others would be using the old dependent app. Changing anything in dependent app will affect other parents also. So its better to make a new one.

Comment: is it a parent pom or just a dependency?

Comment: Where is your code? what shall we help you with? please post the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the spring-beans dependency from parent project dependency in pom.xml and add the dependency with proper version that you want.

Example:
In pom.xml:

```
<dependeny>
   <artifactId>parent<\artifactId>
   <groupId>parent<groupId>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and add proper dependency:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks...Yes that could help, but I am not the owner of the parent project hence cannot remove the dependencies. And also cant ask to delete as it may impact other thing

Comment: you exclude it in your pom.xml

Comment: then how will I compile my project

Comment: Basically you try to remove the version coming from parent and add your beans manually.

Comment: but that will be a lot of code changes to add all the beans manually

Comment: u just need to add lib which you are excluding

Comment: "org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire cannot be cast to org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire"

that is why this issue is coming, since there is version a mismatch